# Get last date in variable in a long data format in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a long data format, where I need to create a variable with the last date for each id.

Example data

```
id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)

event_date <- c("2000.01.11",
                "2000.02.11",
                "2000.03.08", #id_max for id 1
                
                "2018.06.15",
                "2018.07.07",
                "2018.08.10", #id_max for id 1
                "2018.07.15",
                
                "2020.01.19",
                "2020.02.19", #id_max for id 1 
                "2020.01.15")

df <- tibble::tibble(id, event_date)
```

```
# This is what I want: 
df$id_max <- c("2000.03.08","2000.03.08","2000.03.08",
            "2018.08.10","2018.08.10","2018.08.10","2018.08.10",
            "2020.02.19","2020.02.19","2020.02.19")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `event_date` to Date column and get `max` date for each `id`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(event_date = as.Date(event_date, '%Y.%m.%d')) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(id_max = max(event_date))

#      id event_date id_max    
#   <dbl> <date>     <date>    
# 1     1 2000-01-11 2000-03-08
# 2     1 2000-02-11 2000-03-08
# 3     1 2000-03-08 2000-03-08
# 4     2 2018-06-15 2018-08-10
# 5     2 2018-07-07 2018-08-10
# 6     2 2018-08-10 2018-08-10
# 7     2 2018-07-15 2018-08-10
# 8     3 2020-01-19 2020-02-19
# 9     3 2020-02-19 2020-02-19
#10     3 2020-01-15 2020-02-19
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not use to much dplyr or tibble. I prefer data.table. But this is made with base R.

```
id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
 
event_date <- c("2000.01.11",
            "2000.02.11",
            "2000.03.08", #id_max for id 1
            
            "2018.06.15",
            "2018.07.07",
            "2018.08.10", #id_max for id 1
            "2018.07.15",
            
            "2020.01.19",
            "2020.02.19", #id_max for id 1 
            "2020.01.15")
#Get max() number in date row
md<-aggregate(df$event_date,by=list(id),max)

####OPTIONAL###
#Force date conversion substituting (.)
df["good_date"]<-gsub("\\.","-",event_date)
########

#Finally Create column with max date
merge(df,md,by.x=1,by.y=1)
#    id event_date          x
#1   1 2000.01.11 2000.03.08
#2   1 2000.02.11 2000.03.08
#3   1 2000.03.08 2000.03.08
#4   2 2018.06.15 2018.08.10
#5   2 2018.07.07 2018.08.10
#6   2 2018.08.10 2018.08.10
#7   2 2018.07.15 2018.08.10
#8   3 2020.01.19 2020.02.19
#9   3 2020.02.19 2020.02.19
#10  3 2020.01.15 2020.02.19

#Or if you made de as.Date() conversion

md<-aggregate(df$good_date,by=list(id),max)
merge(df,md,by.x=1,by.y=1)
#    id event_date  good_date          x
#1   1 2000.01.11 2000-01-11 2000-03-08
#2   1 2000.02.11 2000-02-11 2000-03-08
#3   1 2000.03.08 2000-03-08 2000-03-08
#4   2 2018.06.15 2018-06-15 2018-08-10
#5   2 2018.07.07 2018-07-07 2018-08-10
#6   2 2018.08.10 2018-08-10 2018-08-10
#7   2 2018.07.15 2018-07-15 2018-08-10
#8   3 2020.01.19 2020-01-19 2020-02-19
#9   3 2020.02.19 2020-02-19 2020-02-19
#10  3 2020.01.15 2020-01-15 2020-02-19
```